# AWS Lambda Java function to update query in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, java-8, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS lambda, I have created sample lambda function and deploy it successfully. Now I want to connect my lambda with Mongodb and need to update collection using query but didn't get any information for the same.

I have tried integrating spring in lambda but after researching I found out that spring is not recommended and not good practice to use in lambda. I want to connect to the MongoDB database.

Below is the sample java code.

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {


    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(Object o, Context context) {

        System.out.println("welcome to lambda function yeh.!!!");

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily connect to MongoDB without Spring.

There are a [lot of tutorials](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-java-part-i) out there which will help you.

For using it inside lambda, make sure to

- package all your dependencies correctly (e.g. use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/))
- handle your connections manually, as your application is not running continuously. That's not a trivial task, but there are also a lot of [sources online how to do this](https://blog.webiny.com/using-aws-lambda-to-create-a-mongodb-connection-proxy-2bb53c4a0af4).

As this is SO, you should try to do your first implementation yourself & if you're facing issues, please post your code and you'll get further support!

Answer (score 1):

added below maven dependency in pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

> written below code in handler to update query in mongoDB .

```
@Override
    public Object handleRequest(Object o, Context context) {

        System.out.println("welcome to lambda function yeh.!!!");
        try {
            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
            DBCollection col = db.getCollection("contact");
            System.out.println("data count" + col.count());

            BasicDBObject setValue = new BasicDBObject();
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.put("contacts.mobileNo", "7090909090");
            setValue.put("contacts.$.userId", "userId12121212");
            BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", setValue);
            col.updateMulti(query, set);
            //close resources
            mongo.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```